# Square Matrix Multiply Recursive vs. Traditional Way

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, matrix-multiplication

I implemented two algorithms for square matrix multiplication. `multiply_normal` is the traditional way, which uses 3 nested for loops and `multiply` is a recursive approach.

However, even though the `multiply_normal` algorithm gives the correct output, the other algorithm seems to fail to output correct result.

Here is the whole code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int a[][] = { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };
        int b[][] = { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };

        print(multiply_normal(a, b));

        System.out.println();

        print(multiply(a, b));

    }

    public static int[][] multiply(int[][] A, int[][] B) {

        int n = A.length;

        int[][] R = new int[n][n];

        if (n == 1)

            R[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0];

        else {

            int[][] A11 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] A12 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] A21 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] A22 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] B11 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] B12 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] B21 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];
            int[][] B22 = new int[n / 2][n / 2];

            split(A, A11, 0, 0);
            split(A, A12, 0, n / 2);
            split(A, A21, n / 2, 0);
            split(A, A22, n / 2, n / 2);

            split(B, B11, 0, 0);
            split(B, B12, 0, n / 2);
            split(B, B21, n / 2, 0);
            split(B, B22, n / 2, n / 2);

            // P:=M2+M3−M6−M7
            int[][] C11 = add(multiply(A11, B11), multiply(A12, B21));

            // Q:=M4+M6
            int[][] C12 = add(multiply(A11, B12), multiply(A12, B22));

            // R:=M5+M7
            int[][] C21 = add(multiply(A21, B11), multiply(A22, B21));

            // S:=M1−M3−M4−M5
            int[][] C22 = add(multiply(A21, B12), multiply(A22, B22));

            // Step 3: Join 4 halves into one result matrix
            join(C11, R, 0, 0);
            join(C12, R, 0, n / 2);
            join(C21, R, n / 2, 0);
            join(C22, R, n / 2, n / 2);
        }

        // Step 4: Return result
        return R;
    }

    // Method 2
    // Function to subtract two matrices
    public int[][] sub(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
        //
        int n = A.length;

        //
        int[][] C = new int[n][n];

        // Iterating over elements of 2D matrix
        // using nested for loops

        // Outer loop for rows
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

            // Inner loop for columns
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

                // Subtracting corresponding elements
                // from matrices
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] - B[i][j];

        // Returning the resultant matrix
        return C;
    }

    // Method 3
    // Function to add two matrices
    public static int[][] add(int[][] A, int[][] B) {

        //
        int n = A.length;

        // Creating a 2D square matrix
        int[][] C = new int[n][n];

        // Iterating over elements of 2D matrix
        // using nested for loops

        // Outer loop for rows
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

            // Inner loop for columns
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

                // Adding corresponding elements
                // of matrices
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];

        // Returning the resultant matrix
        return C;
    }

    // Method 4
    // Function to split parent matrix
    // into child matrices
    public static void split(int[][] P, int[][] C, int iB, int jB) {
        // Iterating over elements of 2D matrix
        // using nested for loops

        // Outer loop for rows
        for (int i1 = 0, i2 = iB; i1 < C.length; i1++, i2++)

            // Inner loop for columns
            for (int j1 = 0, j2 = jB; j1 < C.length; j1++, j2++)

                C[i1][j1] = P[i2][j2];
    }

    // Method 5
    // Function to join child matrices
    // into (to) parent matrix
    public static void join(int[][] C, int[][] P, int iB, int jB)

    {
        // Iterating over elements of 2D matrix
        // using nested for loops

        // Outer loop for rows
        for (int i1 = 0, i2 = iB; i1 < C.length; i1++, i2++)

            // Inner loop for columns
            for (int j1 = 0, j2 = jB; j1 < C.length; j1++, j2++)

                P[i2][j2] = C[i1][j1];
    }

    public static int[][] multiply_normal(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
        int n = A.length;

        int C[][] = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                C[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return C;
    }

    public static void print(int[][] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of `multiply_normal` (inputs are in the main method):

```
6 6 6 
12 12 12 
18 18 18
```

The output of `multiply`:

```
3 3 0 
6 6 0 
0 0 0
```

So, where am I mistaken? What should I do to fix that? I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: multiply_normal is the method name that uses 3 for loops to multiply. The other is named `multiply`, which is a recursive way to multiply two matrices.

Comment: TL;DR are you aware that in the given example n/2 = 1 ?

Comment: Ah you are right, thank you very much! I wasn't aware of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having reviewed the code briefly: In the given example n/2 equals 1 which is probably not what you wanted.
I expect both methods to produce the same result for an even size (say 4x4) matrix.